# form.label is not showing in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

this is my code and I try to show the label but it is not displaying

this is my form file
forms.py

```
class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['value', 'body']
        labels = {'value': 'Place your vote', 'body': 'Add a comment with your vote'}
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReviewForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})
```

this is my views file and the function for this form
views.py

```
def project(request, pk):
    projectObj = Project.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ReviewForm()
    context = {
        'project': projectObj,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'projects/single-project.html', context)
```

this is the model for the review section
models.py

```
class Review(models.Model):
    VOTE_TYPE = (
        ('up', 'Up Vote'),
        ('down', 'Down Vote')
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=VOTE_TYPE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default = uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    
    class Meta:
        # every user can only have single comment on each project
        unique_together = [['owner', 'project']]


    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

and the html file to display the form
html file

```
<form class="form" action="{% url 'project' project.owner.id %}" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {% for field in form %}
              <div class="form__field">
                <label for="formInput#textarea">{{field.label}}</label>
                {{field}}
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
              <input class="btn btn--sub btn--lg" type="submit" value="Comments" />
            </form>
```

I try to show form.label but it is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

the label is contained in the **label_tag** property in the field:

```html
<form class="form" action="{% url 'project' project.owner.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form__field">
            <label for="formInput#textarea">{{field.label_tag}}</label>
            {{field}}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input class="btn btn--sub btn--lg" type="submit" value="Comments" />
</form>
```

Are you sure for your **labels** property of Meta class of ModelForm, i do not known this property. You probably need to redefine your field with label you want to, or update field label in the init function of your form.

```py
class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['value', 'body']
        labels = {'value': 'Place your vote', 'body': 'Add a comment with your vote'}


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReviewForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})
```

Comment: unfortunately label_tag doesn't work too and the self.fields["value"].label = 'Place your vote'
        self.fields["body"].label = 'Add a comment with your vote'

Comment: yes i checked for labels Meta property, it is ok finally